# Using elm higher order functions for keyboard events

Tags: functional-programming, dom-events, elm

I am trying to create a higher order function to create functions to capture only a specific key code. The code is inspired on Evan's `onEnter` function from his todomvc implementation which captures only the enter function.

```
onKeyCode : Int -> Msg -> Attribute Msg
onKeyCode keycode msg =
    let
        captureKey code =
            if code == keycode then
                msg
            else
                NoOp
    in
        on "keydown" (Json.map captureKey keyCode)

onEnter = onKeyCode 13
onEsc =  onKeyCode 27
```

And now I want to add that to an input component in the viewer:

```
input
 [ class "edit"
 , id ("todo-" ++ toString item.uid)
 , value item.message
 , onInput (UpdateItem item.uid)
 , onBlur (SwitchEditTodo item.uid False)
 , onEnter (SwitchEditTodo item.uid False)
 , onEsc (UndoEditTodo item.uid)
 ]
[]
```

If I only have the `onEnter` the code will work as expected but if I add the `onEsc`, the `onEnter` code is never executed. Where am I doing the mistake? is that a problem with the higher order function context or "on" mapping with multiple values in separate functions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are adding two `onkeydown` attributes to the input element, and only one of them can win. The second in the list overwrites the first. Were it to use `addEventListener` behind the scenes, this would not be the case, but for now we can solve it with a slightly different approach.

You could write a `onKeysDown` function that accepts a list of possible key codes and the message they should invoke like this:

```elm
onKeysDown : List (Int, Msg) -> Attribute Msg
onKeysDown keys =
  let
    captureKey code =
      List.filterMap (\(k, m) -> if k == code then Just m else Nothing) keys
        |> List.head
        |> Maybe.withDefault NoOp
  in
    on "keydown" (Json.map captureKey keyCode)
```

You could then write shorthand functions for handling specific keys like this:

```elm
enter msg = (13, msg)
esc msg = (27, msg)
```

And now you can use it in your view like this:

```elm
input
    [ ...
    , onKeysDown
      [ enter <| SwitchEditTodo item.uid False
      , esc <| UndoEditTodo item.uid
      ]
    ]
```

This works because it generates a single `keydown` event handler attribute. And while you substitute a predefined tuple for a higher order function, it still gives you just as readable code.

Comment: From your comment, I understand that this overwriting effect is a side effect emerging from html/JavaScript, because even if I have created several "on" events I am after all just calling the JavaScript API under the cover which allows me to overwrite myself.

Comment: Correct, it's a limitation of multiple html attributes of the same name, not a limitation of Elm (though some warning would be nice). You'll see the same problem if you try to do the same thing in raw html