# How to handle Enter key press in input field?

Tags: elm

I built a simple app for learning purposes and want to be able to dispatch an action when the user presses `Enter` key in input field

```
view : Model -> Html Action
  view model = 
    let 
      items = List.map (\ item -> li [] [ text item ]) model.items
    in
      div [] [
       input [ onInput Change, value model.content ] [],
       button [ onClick Add ] [ text "Submit" ],
       ul [] items
      ]
```

Here is the view code. I hope it will be enough to explain my intent for you. What I'd like to have is ability to dispatch some action when user presses the `Enter` key while he is entering some text to input field.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can manually bind to the `keydown` event with the generic `on` handler. Elm does currently not support `onKeyDown` handlers out of the box - but they are planned in the future.

> It looks like the spec is moving away from event.keyCode and towards event.key. Once this is supported in more browsers, we may add helpers here for onKeyUp, onKeyDown, onKeyPress, etc. ([Source](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/1.1.0/Html-Events#keyCode))

Until then you can simply write your own handler and use keycode 13 (enter) to perform your actions. Open the following [ellie-app](https://ellie-app.com/5JdMMc5M2mpa1) to see how it works. 
Just enter some text in the input box and press enter to see the current state reflected in the div below the input box.

```
import Html exposing (text, div, input, Attribute)
import Browser
import Html.Events exposing (on, keyCode, onInput)
import Json.Decode as Json


main =
  Browser.sandbox 
  { init = 
    { savedText = ""
    , currentText = ""
    }
  , view = view
  , update = update
  }


view model =
  div [] 
  [ input [onKeyDown KeyDown, onInput Input] []
  , div [] [ text ("Input: " ++ model.savedText) ]
  ]

onKeyDown : (Int -> msg) -> Attribute msg
onKeyDown tagger =
  on "keydown" (Json.map tagger keyCode)


type Msg 
  = NoOp
  | KeyDown Int
  | Input String


update msg model =
  case msg of

    NoOp ->
      model

    KeyDown key ->
      if key == 13 then
        { model | savedText = model.currentText }
      else
        model

    Input text ->
      { model | currentText = text }
```

Comment: it looks like you made custom event handler. Can you give some brief explanation on what is going on, please ?

Comment: @NikitaLuparev keyCode is a JSON decoder documented at the same page that was quoted in the answer above

Answer (score 22):

There's a good, straightforward solution to handling `onEnter` in the [Elm version of TodoMVC](https://github.com/evancz/elm-todomvc/blob/166e5f2afc704629ee6d03de00deac892dfaeed0/Todo.elm#L237-L246):

```elm
import Html exposing (Attribute)
import Html.Events exposing (keyCode, on)
import Json.Decode as Json

onEnter : Msg -> Attribute Msg
onEnter msg =
    let
        isEnter code =
            if code == 13 then
                Json.succeed msg
            else
                Json.fail "not ENTER"
    in
        on "keydown" (Json.andThen isEnter keyCode)
```

Comment: Where is keyCode coming from? Apparently from `Html.Events`.

Comment: Yes, keyCode comes from [Html.Events](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/latest/Html-Events#keyCode) I updated the post with import statement to clarify.

Answer (score 5):

You could use something like this in your `input` element,
this will fire the given message if enter key gets pressed down:

```elm
onEnterPressed : msg -> Attribute msg
onEnterPressed msg =
  let
    isEnter code =
      if code == 13 then Ok () else Err ""
    decodeEnterKeyCode = Json.customDecoder keyCode isEnter
  in on "keydown" <| Json.map (\_ -> msg) decodeEnterKeyCode
```

Comment: Already on community package http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/html-extra/latest/Html-Events-Extra#onEnter

Answer (score 5):

The above answers were very good - but storing ***each letter*** in the `Model` ***on every key press*** - is not always a good idea.

For example in my case i have a `fileSystem`-like strucutre - and i want to edit any name - no matter how nested it is - on `doubbleclick`. I can't have the hole `fileSystem` ***view reconstructed with each key press***. It's laggy.

I found that it's best ***to receive the input value - only when the user presses Enter***..

```
type Msg =
    | EditingStarted
    | EditingFinished String
    | CancelEdit

input [ whenEnterPressed_ReceiveInputValue EditingFinished, whenEscPressed_CancelOperation CancelEdit, onBlur CancelEdit ] []

update msg model =
    case msg of
        EditingFinished inputValue ->
            { model | name = inputValue }
        CancelEdit -> ...


whenEnterPressed_ReceiveInputValue : (String -> msg) -> H.Attribute msg
whenEnterPressed_ReceiveInputValue tagger =
  let
    isEnter code =
        if code == 13 then
            JD.succeed "Enter pressed"
        else
            JD.fail "is not enter - is this error shown anywhere?!"

    decode_Enter =
        JD.andThen isEnter E.keyCode
  in
    E.on "keydown" (JD.map2 (\key value -> tagger value) decode_Enter E.targetValue)


whenEscPressed_CancelOperation : msg -> H.Attribute msg
whenEscPressed_CancelOperation tagger =
  let
    isESC code =
        if code == 27 then
            JD.succeed "ESC pressed"
        else
            JD.fail "it's not ESC"

    decodeESC =
        JD.andThen isESC E.keyCode
  in
    E.on "keydown" (JD.map (\key -> tagger) decodeESC)
```

Note: If you are doing time-traveling debugging - you will ***not*** see each letter appearing as it was typed. But all text at once - because there was only one msg.. Depending on what you do - this can be a problem. If not, Enjoy :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work because multiple handlers for the same event, `keydown` in this case, aren't supported: https://github.com/elm-lang/virtual-dom/issues/17. See this answer for a working solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/39726025/4618482

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to use the community package `Html.Events.Extra` http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/html-extra/latest/Html-Events-Extra#onEnter it is very easy.

(Assuming that you want to send the `Add` message when the enter key is pressed.)

```
import Html.Events.Extra exposing (onEnter)

view : Model -> Html Action
  view model = 
    let 
      items = List.map (\ item -> li [] [ text item ]) model.items
    in
      div [] [
       input [ onInput Change, onEnter Add, value model.content ] [],
       button [ onClick Add ] [ text "Submit" ],
       ul [] items
      ]
```

Comment: or just copy only this function

Answer (score 2):

I liked Alon's answer and iterated on it a bit to create an attribute that responds to `<enter>` and `<esc>`

```
onEscEnter : String -> (String -> msg) -> Attribute msg
onEscEnter originalValue tagger =
    let
        handleKey : Int -> Jdec.Decoder Int
        handleKey code =
            if L.member code [ 13, 27 ] then
                -- Enter (13) or ESC (27)
                Jdec.succeed code
            else
                Jdec.fail "something to ignore"

        combiner : Int -> String -> msg
        combiner keyCode tgtVal =
            if keyCode == 13 then
                tagger tgtVal
            else if keyCode == 27 then
                tagger originalValue
            else
                Debug.crash "onEscEnter"

        keyCodeDecoder : Jdec.Decoder Int
        keyCodeDecoder =
            Jdec.andThen handleKey keyCode
    in
        on "keydown" (Jdec.map2 combiner keyCodeDecoder targetValue)
```